# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

> (node:55028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at /Users/patrickstanciu/WebstormProjects/autismassistant/backend/api/controllers/paymentsController.js:1045:34
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
>   (node:55028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
>   This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:55028) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have this error in my node.js backend when I try to login with an user. Why does it appear? 
Here is the line:

```
   if (!profilePromise.rows.length) {
            resolve({
                success: true,
                cardDetails: null,
                planId: null
            })
            return;
        }
```

I have problems with "length" above

Answer (score 1):

Based on the name, `profilePromise` is a promise. Promises don't have a `rows` property, so `profilePromise.rows` is `undefined` and you can't read any properties from `undefined`.

You need to *consume* the promise and use its fulfillment value, which I'm guessing is something with a `length` property:

```
profilePromise
.then(rows => {
    if (rows.length) {
        resolve(/*...*/);
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report the error...
    // Probably `reject` here?
});
```

More about using promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

---

Side note: Assuming I'm right that `profilePromise` is indeed a promise, it suggests that this code is falling prey to [the explicit promise creation antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Instead of creating your own promise and then calling `resolve` or `reject`, chain onto the existing promise:

```
return profilePromise
    .then(rows => {
        if (rows.length) {
            return {
                success: true,
                cardDetails: null,
                planId: null
            };
        }
        // Either return something else here, or `throw` if `rows` not having
        // a truthy `length` is an error
    });
```